# how to fix odom and map frame on rviz

Tags: navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have two ekf nodes (one fusing GPS, the other not) and I wish to compare their trajectories. I understand that rviz overlays the trajectories and allows the odom and map frame to drift. Is there an easy way to disable this? I wish to keep the odom and map frames fixed with respect to each other and watch the paths drift from each other.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328677/how-to-fix-odom-and-map-frame-on-rviz/) by [Mrbl](https://answers.ros.org/users/44071/mrbl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you can only have one frame fixed. So you need to choose either the one or the other.

I'm not sure why your two ekf nodes work in different frames. Is the one including GPS using the map frame?

What you could do anyways is to create a node that listens to both transforms and publishes what you want in a common frame.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0